# In Edge of Tomorrow, what is Tom Cruise's exosuit saying when he can't turn his safety off? (Japanese)

Tags: analysis, dialogue, translation, edge-of-tomorrow

In the beginning of the movie, Cruise has his safety enabled and accidentally switches his suit's HUD to Japanese.

What is the translation of the suit's audio when he can't fire?

It's probably something mundane like "safety engaged", but I've always been curious.

[image]

Comment: Try asking this in the [Japanese Stack Exchange](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/), since this is more language than movie related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first two characters are Anzen (安全) or "Safety". The last two characters (オン) are just a transliteration of the English word "On", as in "switched on".

Comment: The suit actually speaks too [two phrases in all, I think], but my very limited Japanese can only identify the 'polite-isms' in it, not the actual sense of the speech.

Comment: Yes, I'm also interested in knowing what the suit is saying.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question. I'll try to find the captions for that scene, or maybe a clip with slightly clearer audio.